# Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04 - minimal c/c++ installation

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

I want to use Eclipse IDE for developing C/C++ applications. When I've tried `sudo apt-get install eclipse`I noticed that it will install a lot of packages which seems to be unnecessary for me. Which packages I should install to get Eclipse IDE for developing C/C++ applications ?

Comment: "I noticed that it will install a lot of packages which seems to be unnecessary for me" please list them. What you think unnecessary might be a must to the creator of the package :+

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: [installing eclipse on ubuntu](http://akovid.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/installing-eclipse-juno-42-in-ubuntu.html)

Good luck!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.